# How to prevent a Mongoose Node await request from returning data?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, async-await

When we make a run of the mill await Mongoose request (Node) like so.

```
await Model.findOneAndUpdate().lean();
```

As we can see above I have not placed the returning result into a object, which means I do not need it. How to instruct it to return nothing thus saving time sending back unrequired data ?
My guess is maybe it does that anyways automatically in the request ?

Additionally if I do so

```
const [item1] = await Promise.all([
    promises1,
    promise2
]);
```

How to instruct the second promise to not bother returning anything ?

Thanks

Daniel

Comment: In your first example you are already optimising the query by chaining `lean()` which stops mongoose from turning the resulting POJO into an instance of the mongoose Document class. However, since mongoose queries are not promises you need call it's `then()` function or use `await` (with or without `exec()` - which will return a promise) otherwise the query won't execute. The fact that you don't do anything with the returned value is irrelevant - Node needs to know when the asynchronous task is complete/errors during the event loop so it can carry on execution of that function.

Comment: So in the first example, does mongo send back the leaned object/data ? Even though I do not declare it into a function ? Does that object still get transferred over the network thus causing a longer wait time for that promise to resolve ?

Comment: Mongoose will resolve with POJO yes (or reject with an error). You have to remember this is all done on the server by Node. If your mongodb instance is remote then there will be latency as the request is sent over the network from your server to your cluster via the mongoose connection and then the resolved object sent back but if your Express/Next server and mongodb instance are on the same server then there is nothing being sent over the network. Your biggest latency will be between client and sever.

Comment: I connect my NextJS to mongodb so this is all a three way thing. Currently what I do is use select find().select("tiny-element").lean() to return the smallest. trying to find out is their a better way to instruct mondo to return nothing as no need, hard questions to find answers to. One would think there would be an option like { returnNothing: true }